discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "coucou" is not found
I'm trying to create a bot Discord with Python.
I created a class MyBot like this:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, description="My Bot !!")
    
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("My Bot is Online !")

    async def coucou(ctx):
        await ctx.send("You say coucou, i say coucou !")

And in my main.py I have:
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from Classbot.class_bot import MyBot as MB

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(dotenv_path="config")

bot = MB()
bot.coucou()
bot.run(os.getenv("mytoken"))

The bot is online and I have the message "My Bot is Online !" but in Discord when I try: !coucou, I get this error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "coucou" is not found

I don't succeed in calling the method coucou.
It works if I don't create a class and put all the code in the same main.py page but I want to use a class.

The issue you're facing is because coucou is not defined as a command in your bot's code, while you defined coucou in your MyBot class, it is not registered as a command
Add that to declare your function as a command
@bot.command()
You can see more at this link
Then look at the Cogs to organize a collection of commands, listeners...

Have you tried doing it in just one file? Example:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"My Bot is Online !")

@bot.command()
async def coucou(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You say coucou, i say coucou !")

bot.run("TOKEN")


Hello Jay, i have tried this in one file yes and it works well ! But i want to do this with Class and method...

why do you need a class and method? also if this worked, please mark my answer as the successful answer, for in this case mine was the correct one.
